# Google Spaces change user role in app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a project where at a point I need to turn a user from a member of a space to a manager, but simple sending a json to the endpoint with the new role wont do it and creating a user automatically has their role be member no matter what you change it to. Does anyone have experience with this?

I need to create google app script that'll change a users role in a space using the space id and the user id